# How to query using linq statements?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects

```
List<Report> 
List<Newsletter>
```

I need certain properties like

```
Id
Date
Status
text
```

from the two lists. Is there a way to merge these list and query it using linq statement to return the specific properties as a separate list?
Please help.

Structure of the object is as follows:

```
Report
{
    int id,
    datetime reportDate, 
    enum Status,
    string text
};

Newsletter
{
    int id, 
    datetime newsletterDate,
    string Status,
    string text
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to join them? Do they share a common property?

Comment: Most interesting poinht. So far the answer is YES; THIS IS POSSIBLE - theoretically. No idea how you would do it here, because I am not even sure they have a simila structure.

Comment: CreatedBy property is common to both

Comment: I think perhaps a `union` is required, if not, what is the sutructure of each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var items = 
      reportList.Select(x =>  new { x.Id, x.Date, x.Status, x.text })
      .Concat(
        newsList.Select(x =>  new { x.Id, x.Date, x.Status, x.text }) );
```

---

Update, to equalize the Status properties:

```
var items = 
      reportList.Select(x =>  new { x.Id, x.Date, Status = x.Status.ToString(), x.text })
      .Concat(
        newsList.Select(x =>  new { x.Id, x.Date, Status, x.text }) );
```

Comment: There is some mismatch in the property Status in both objects. I need to convert that to a string. How can i do that within the anonymous object?

Comment: Note: Concat over Union because there seems to be no req to remove duplicates.

Comment: one more doubt. Does the property name should match in the selector part? My property name for 'ID' differs in both object. The type is same.

Comment: Then you have to use `Id = x.Id` or similar. They have to match to make the Concat/Union work.

Comment: It _is_ a LINQ expression. Just not a query.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that both the list contains the common columns and applying join between them..

you can aply join and then get the data as below

```
var data = form a in lista
join b in listb on
a.id equals b.id
select new {id=a.id, Date= b.Date, Status=a.Sttus, text=b.Text};
```

following is image of join between two table user and userclient

Check full article : [Case 4 - JOINING TWO TABLE](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
var reps = reposts.Select(r => new { Id = r.Id, Date = r.Date, Status = r.Status, Text = r.Text});
var news = newsletters.Select(n => new { Id = r.Id, Date = r.Date, Status = r.Status, Text = r.Text});
var result = reps.Union(news);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 var query = reports.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Date, Status = Enum.GetName(typeof(Status), x.Status), x.Text })
.Union(news.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Date, x.Status, x.Text }));
```

Comment: This wont work in the above case. It's returning error cause of the mismatch in the types of the properties.

Comment: Yours and Henk's answers are the same. I have one more doubt. Does the property name should match in the selector part? My property name for 'ID' differs in both object. The type is same.

Comment: yes they should match, but it's not an issue because you can assign another name to the property in the annonymous type Id=x.AnotherId